# c# mongodb Find and remove one element from an array selected among several documents

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm a newbie in a `document-oriented database` in general and in `MongoDB` in particular.

This database was created by me: a collection of several disjoint segments containing integers.

[image]

I'd like to take one item in accordance with some conditions and remove it from the document.

For example, I tried to take the item with conditions:

1. from [-105; 17]
2. not zero
3. contains in {-104, -97, -5, 0, 5}

like this

```
var db          = client.GetDatabase("mongodbPOC");
var collection  = db.GetCollection<Document>("Int");
var contains    = new List<int> { -104, -97, -5, 0, 5 };
var result      = collection.AsQueryable()
                            .Where(document => 17 >= document.Min && -105 <= document.Max)
                            .SelectMany(document => document.Values)
                            .First(val => val != 0 && contains.Contains(val));
```

and find it again for remove, but I sure that exists a more profitable way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remove finding a solution was not easy, but they helped me on the `MongoDB` forum in `slack`. To solve this problem there are two ways:

1. using `agg expressions` in `4.2` for values where the position is known or unknown(Asya's answer): https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1014?focusedCommentId=2305681&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2305681
2. using `$unset` followed by `$pullAll` to remove all `null`'s

Answer (score 2):

To remove items from array in `MongoDb`, you need to use `Pull` or `PullFilter`, in your case, you need to use `PullFilter`, like this:

```
var filterPull = Builders<int>.Filter
                              .Where(x => x != 0 && contains.Contains(x));
var update = Builders<YourModel>.Update
                                .PullFilter(c => c.Values, filterPull);
```

Then create another filter for Min, Max condition, this filter is for your document and use Update Collection:

```
var filter = Builders<YourModel>.Filter
                                .Where(document => 17 >= document.Min && -105 <= document.Max);
Collection.UpdateManyAsync(filter, update);
```

Comment: How to get the taken and deleted value(value from  `result` in my attempt)?
And why you suggest `UpdateManyAsync` if the one item in one array is needed to delete?

Comment: And it doesn't work, it returns me `System.AggregateException: "WriteEncodin"`, inner exception: `InvalidOperationException: {document} is not supported.
`

Comment: UpdateManyAsync mean you can update multiple documents, it has nothing todo with your array, if you only need one item in one array, you need to change the filterPull

Comment: With this way, the only thing you can get is the number of affected documents by your query, if you want to get deleted values, your way is correct

Comment: when I replaced `PullFilter` to `Pull` it stars working, but it removes all elements from the array which fit the condition, but I want to remove only one element.